# Domain Gripping

Tags: website, domain, domain-name, web-hosting

Here's a pretty newb/101 question I have here. I'm very new to web hosting and domain forwarding. I just opened up my first web hosting site, and I'm trying to figure out a problem I'm having with the domain forwarding. I hope I can explain this right.

Let's say my website is called Website, and the domain I bought is website.com, which redirects to webhost.com/IP 1.1.1.1. When the user types in www.website.com, I obviously want the address bar to stay as "www.website.com" instead of "webhost.com" or "1.1.1.1/~myusername" or whatever. When the user navigates to buymycrap.html, the address bar should say "www.website.com/buymycrap.html." However, I'm getting one of the following two things, depending on what settings I use at my domain registrar:

1. The address bar will always say "www.website.com," but if the user navigates to a page and hits refresh, they'll be bumped back to the index page. I want them to remain on whatever page they're at. I also get problems with external links where the user won't be able to navigate externally unless I add the target="_blank" attribute to my anchors.
2. The user will be able to navigate to different pages on my site and refresh back to those pages, and external links will work fine, but the true address (i.e. www.webhost.com) will show up on the address bar.

Through research, I know this has to do with domain gripping, but no matter what I'm setting, I can't get my desired result. Does anybody have any tips on what's going on here? Thanks!

On the domain registrant's side (namespro.ca), I have this:

- domain name: inagalaxyfarfarawry.com
- name servers: slns1.namespro.ca (67.228.254.4) and slns2.namespro.ca (67.228.255.5)
- type: Domain forwarding
- forward to: http://ns2.sslcatacombnetworking.com/~inagalax

The web hosting side (siteflip.com) doesn't really provide any information other than the whois stuff, which is above.

When I contacted namespro.ca about web gripping, they responded with:

> We hope you understand that is simply a smart browser trick.   There is limitation on what the gripping function can do.  What you describe relates to how the web server settings are at "http://ns2.sslcatacombnetworking.com/~inagalax/".  It is also not what a domain gripping function is designed to do.  The only way would be to have the host at "sslcatacombnetworking.com" take on your domain as a http header, but we are not sure their admin would agree to that.

Comment: It sounds like you are on the right track, but there may be a misunderstanding of how the web host works. Unfortunately, you didn't provide much information about your web host or configuration. This is where the problem lies. It is the URL redirection that is not working. Your webhost is not

Comment: Oops I hit send. Your webhost is not handling the URL redirection properly.  It doesn't understand that www.website.com/yourstuff.html is actually www.webhost.com/~username/yourstuff.html. Could be a hosting config problem or a website config problem on your end. Details are specific to the host and underlying software.

Comment: Hey, @Appleoddity, thanks for the reply. What info do you need me to provide? Lemme know, and I can put it in here.

Comment: Well, it would help to know the hosting provider and what type of plan you are using. This would help in finding documentation. Have you spoken with the hosting provider at all?

Comment: Please name both your hosting and domain provider, if they’re different.

Comment: Sorry for the reply after so long, guys. I've edited my original post with the info you asked. If I'm missing anything, let me know and I can dig it up. Thanks!